# Cant install PHP 7.2 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, 20.04, php7

I  added ondrej PPA. And tried install php 7.2, but looks like PPA has not been updated yet. What are my workarounds?

Comment: I have a solution for working with php7.2 and apache2 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231381/unable-to-install-php-7-3-on-ubuntu-20

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install PHP 7.3 on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231381/unable-to-install-php-7-3-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 42):

Follow the steps described below.

1. Add the PPA maintained by Ondrej Surý:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
   ```
2. Install PHP version 7.2:

   ```
   sudo apt install php7.2
   ```
3. Select the standard version of PHP:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
   ```
4. Disable version 7.4 or the one you are using:

   ```
   sudo a2dismod php7.4
   ```
5. Enable version 7.2:

   ```
   sudo a2enmod php7.2:
   ```
6. Restart the Apache server

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how do u verify if the apache2 is using php 7.2 ?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ Try `echo` `phpinfo()` to see current version of php.  Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding the eoan/main PPA... Although, this is likely not a preferred route to follow.

```
$ sudo su
$ cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bkp
$ echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu eoan main" >> $ /etc/apt/sources.list
$ apt update
$ apt install php7.2 php-pear php7.2-gd php7.2-dev  php7.2-zip php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml php7.2-curl
$ exit
```

Comment: This seems to have worked fine for me. I can confirm that I'm running both PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.4 on Apache2 and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Today I just realize that with lates ubuntu PPA update older PHP version is available now. 
So to install php7.3 or 7.2 just sudo apt update and you are ready to go!