# Unable to install PHP 7.3 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, php

I want to install PHP 7.3 on Ubuntu 20.04 for my Nginx web server, when I try to install the 7.4 version everything is fine but for 7.3 I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.3
```

Then, I run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.3
```

But, again, it shows that it can't locate the package. Does Ubuntu 20.04 support PHP 7.3 or below and if it does, what's wrong with my installation procedure?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Perhaps the support wasn't available when you asked the question but all you need to do is as described in your Q.

Add ondrej PPA repository to your system.

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

Install php7.3 and check it's installed.

```
sudo apt install -y php7.3
php -v
```

This also works for php 7.4, php7.2 and php5.6. Just change the relevant digits.

Comment: Nice repo, thanks for the link. Just installed PHP 7.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This solution is also valid for elementary OS 5.1 Hera.

Comment: @joe92 what do u mean by **software-properties-common**

Answer (score 4):

I got my problem solved for php7.2 but not sure about php7.3.

We can still install php7.2 by terminal: `apt install php7.2`.

But we have to install php7.4 too otherwise it will remove the main php package. It may need some research, but here are my instructions (for php7.2):

(`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` won't be necessary, it can be removed)

1. Install php7.2:

   ```
   sudo apt install php7.2
   ```
2. Go to to this link and download the .deb file https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libapache2-mod-php7.2/download (don't install it yet, we have to place it manually in the system)
3. Extract libapache2. There will be a "data" archeive in it. It has two folders `etc` and `usr`. Copy those folders to matching directories of the root.
4. Now to choose php7.2 rather than php7.4,because php7.4 is default, enter these commands

   ```
   sudo a2disconf php7.4-cgi 
   sudo a2dismod php7.4
   sudo a2enconf php7.2-cgi 
   sudo a2enmod php7.2
   sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```
5. Although `php -v` shows version 7.4 (because it's the latest), it still uses php7.2
6. To switch from php7.4 to php7.2 older version:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
   ```
7. Now `php -v` shows version 7.2 as default

It should now work as php7.2

Comment: you can't install any php lower than 7.4 on Ubuntu 20.04 via "apt install php7.2" you get an error: `E: Unable to locate package php7.2`

Answer (score 2):

Today I just realized that with the latest Ubuntu PPA update older PHP versions are available now.

So to install php7.3 or 7.2 just `sudo apt update` and you are ready to go!

Comment: This does not work for me. `apt update; apt install php7.3` produces "E: Unable to locate package php7.3".

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something slightly off about the repository.  I changed the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-focal.list` file for it and changed focal to eoan (19.10 Ubuntu version) and I can see all of the packages again.

I've installed using this but not tested any further.