# Is there a way I can install php 7.2.31 on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: php

Oddly enough I couldn't seem to find anything about this. Baffles me, except I'm an Ubuntu noob (switched over about 6 months ago, and absolutely loving it).

I'm simply trying to install php 7.2.31 (the version my hosting is using) on Ubuntu 20.04. I found an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230869/cant-install-php-7-2-on-ubuntu-20-04) on SE for installing 7.2, but this installed 7.2.34...doh! It would be of great help if I could get a generalized answer here, something to point me in the right direction of installing any version of anything on Ubuntu (or anything:). Thanks hahaha! :)

Comment: Hmmm... Can you explain why the version in repositories isn't working for your use case? Software gets updated all the time, so it's incredibly rare that you need a very specific version. They should have the same functionality, right?

Comment: Why would a slightly newer version be an issue? Unless you’re writing software that needs a very specific quirk that exists in very specific releases, using slightly different numbers should be fine 

Comment: What's with the "*hahaha! :)*" ? Is this some kind of joke question?

Comment: Well it's simply a fact-of-life of my workflow, I'm building a website specifically (on the server) for php 7.2.31, and running php 7.4.x on my sandbox. I would prefer to line everything up on my sandbox, you know, if necessary. Basically, are "revisions" backwards compatible?

Comment: Install anything on anything? That's whats hahaha ;)

Comment: I write a whole bunch of PHP and my local development system uses PHP 7.4 while the servers I deploy to are running 7.1, 7.2, 7.4, and 8.0. So long as you're using standard functions, there should be no issue. If you need 100% alignment, the only way you'll get it is via Docker containers.

Comment: I had a property-typing error in one of my (small) scripts I uploaded to my server. It was a quick fix (just removed the types), but I thought you know it would be a good idea to be strict about this, if possible. That's all.

Comment: My question is basically: are php 7.2.x backwards compatible? I know this is an EXTREMELY retarded question but I thought it would be a killer one to ask here on SE :D

Comment: Pretty sure that version has multiple DOS vulnerabilities. Can you update the hosting version (it probably should be updated)?

Comment: @Cinder Although that does sound like a good question, I think it would be better posted as a separate question to ask if version 7.2.34 is generally backwards compatible with 7.2.31. There really wasn't that many changes aside from the CVE fixes. I posted the changelog below in my answer.

Comment: Your intentions are good but misguided. You're *much* more likely to break something or expose a vulnerability by trying to force a particular package version.  This can be especially destructive when it starts to come to dependencies and there are a lot of dependencies associated with php.  I would leave it alone. Stay with the maintained version unless absolutely necessary. In this case, it doesn't seem to be so

Comment: I'll try docker and see what I get. My only concern is coding thousands of lines of code and then having to pick through them right before publish. I mean this seems like not a good thing. Am I wrong for thinking this?

Comment: Sio I'm trying to install via docker, anyone help me with this? Total noob :D Figured it might be faster to just ask instead of fiddling around all day long.

Comment: Ok so I figure I need this image on docker, can anyone confirm this? https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.2.31-apache-stretch/images/sha256-710cea82add4bb22d5cc5dcfe98a11f5220caa8e2b2374f0ad31c32a9eb39095?context=explore

Comment: So before I go any further why would I not want to do this? How does one code for a particular version of php without a huge mess, otherwise?

Comment: https://github.com/rectorphp/rector

Answer (score 5):

There have been multiple CVEs fixed in subsequent versions since 7.2.31, all the way up to 7.3.34.

You're probably not going to find a vulnerable version to install unless you download it from php directly or build it from source although, not sure you would want to do that just to run a vulnerable version. Also, I'm not sure if vulnerable versions are even available directly from php.

[CVE-2020-7070](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-7070)

[CVE-2020-7069](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-7069)

[CVE-2020-7068](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-7068)

```
Version 7.2.34
01 Oct 2020
Core:
Fixed bug #79699 (PHP parses encoded cookie names so malicious `__Host-` cookies can be sent). (CVE-2020-7070)
OpenSSL:
Fixed bug #79601 (Wrong ciphertext/tag in AES-CCM encryption for a 12 bytes IV). (CVE-2020-7069)


Version 7.2.33
06 Aug 2020
Core:
Fixed bug #79877 (getimagesize function silently truncates after a null byte) (cmb)
Phar:
Fixed bug #79797 (Use of freed hash key in the phar_parse_zipfile function). (CVE-2020-7068)


Version 7.2.32
09 Jul 2020
Windows:
Rebuild of official Windows binaries with patched libcurl. No PHP source changes.
```